# SQL Server database column to keep a running list of 'Notes'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple SQL Server database that stores the following information:

```
Project ID, First Name, Last Name, Project Status, Last Updated, Updated By
```

It keeps track of various projects, who is assigned to them, their status, when the record was last updated, and who last updated the records.

What I want to be able to do next is have a `Notes` column that can store various info about the projects along with a timestamp beside each Note entry. What would be the best way to go about this?

Example:

In the `Notes` column I could have something like

```
Bob ran into x issue (8/20/2020 12pm)
Bob has resolved x issue (8/21/2020 3pm)
```

But then when a new note is added into that column I want the previous notes to still be there, I don't want them to overwrite each other.

Comment: Maintain a table with a separate row for each note.

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon says, it's probably best to keep the notes in a separate table. By having the ProjectId in the note-table you can find the notes that belong to that project. If you really need the notes in one column in your table I would suggest you to use STUFF and 'FOR XML PATH'. Below is a suggestion of how the Note table could look.

[image: NoteTable]

Below is a query that might you get started. If you replace dbo.yourtable and correct column names you should be able get what you are looking for. Please note that temp table is just for explanation. you should have a standard table for your notes.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (NoteID INT,ProjectID INT, NoteText NVARCHAR(50),CreatedAt datetime)

INSERT INTO @temp (NoteID,ProjectID,NoteText,CreatedAt)
VALUES (1,21,'Bob ran into x issue',GETDATE()),(2,21,'Bob has resolved x issue',GETDATE()),(3,99,'Comment for some other project',GETDATE())


SELECT Project ID, First Name, Last Name, Project Status,...,
(SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + NoteText
    FROM @temp
    where ProjectID = T1.ProjectID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')) 

    from dbo.yourTable T1
```

Comment: this is a great idea. Then to display both tables together as one, I would just need to perform a left join on the Project ID's, correct?

Comment: If you do a join you will get two rows (for ProjectID 21, assuming you have one row with projectid 21 in your table). If you want to put the two notes into a single value you can use STUFF with xml path or Pivot.

Comment: yep you're right. Just tried the join and I have repeating rows. I'm not familiar with pivots or STUFF, but in the brief research I just did I believe STUFF will be my best route here

Comment: I've added some more to my answer